# How to access multiple CSV files that share the same name from multiple folders from a zip file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, zip

I have a zip file (stored locally) with multiple folders in it. In each folder are a few CSV files. I need to only access 1 particular CSV from each folder. The CSV's I am trying to access from each folder all share the same name, but I cannot figure out how to access a particular file from each folder, then concatenate them into a pandas df.

I have tried the below (initially trying to read all CSV's):

```
path = r"C:\Users\...\Downloads\folder.zip"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "/*.csv"))

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

But I get: **ValueError: No objects to concatenate.** The CSV's are definitely present and not empty.

I am currently trying to do this in a sagemaker notebook, not sure if that is also causing me problems. Any help would be great.

Comment: you've unzipped the file? because you've not shown how you're handling the zip file in your code

Comment: Is it possible to access the file without unzipping? To save space and time, as the CSV's are quite large.

Comment: `pandas` can read zip files but I'm unsure about zipped directories with multiple csv formats. You'll have to handle the zip file somehow, either in memory or on disk, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: also what's the output of `li` ?

Comment: For handling zipfiles I recommend you have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html . Regarding your "ValueError": That sounds like `li` is empty. Have you made sure that your glob expression works and `all_files` is not an empty list?

Comment: Yes, ```li``` appears to be empty, but not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and advice from Umar.H and mad, I figured out a solution to my original question and to the code example I was originally working with.

The code I was originally working with wasn't working with accessing the zip file directly, so I unzipped the file and tried it on just a regular folder. Amending the empty list of df's `li` to not return an empty list was solved by changing `"/*file.csv"` in all_files to `"*/*file.csv`.

To solve the main issue I had, which was to avoid unzipping the zip file and access all required CSV's I managed to get the following to work

```
PATH = "C:/Users/.../Downloads/folder.zip"

li = []
with zipfile.ZipFile(PATH, "r") as f:
    for name in f.namelist():
        if name.endswith("file.csv"):
            data = f.open(name)
            df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None, low_memory = False)
            li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Hope this can be helpful for anyone else with large zip files.